# Animating :after{content:""} with @keyframes

Tags: css, svg, sass, css-animations

I created this countdown and it works perfectly on Chrome. The problems are on other browsers, where I can't get it to work in the following ways:

Firefox: The numbers CSS content property isn't animated
IE11: Nothing works

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/jonathanpion/pen/jVQRjB) for editing/visualization

Is there a cross-browser way to animate the content property of pseudo elements with @keyframes that's reliable? If not, can you think of another CSS-only way to do the countdown? Also, isn't IE11 supposed to support SVG stroke animation?

Here is the full demo with Sass compiled to CSS:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono");
/*
 * Max value is 5940 seconds
 * ( 99 minutes )
 */
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #abdddb;
}

svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
svg .circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #29bdc0;
  stroke-width: 20px;
  stroke-dasharray: 650;
  stroke-dashoffset: 650;
  animation: circle 121s 0s linear forwards;
  -o-animation: circle 121s 0s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation: circle 121s 0s linear forwards;
  -webkit-animation: circle 121s 0s linear forwards;
}
svg .circle.shadow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  stroke: #000;
  opacity: 0.2;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(2px);
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.mask {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 155px;
  height: 70px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.mask .number {
  display: block;
  width: 155px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  animation: number 0.8s 121.1s ease forwards;
  -o-animation: number 0.8s 121.1s ease forwards;
  -moz-animation: number 0.8s 121.1s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation: number 0.8s 121.1s ease forwards;
}
.mask p {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 2px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -40%);
  animation: done 1s 121.6s ease forwards;
  -o-animation: done 1s 121.6s ease forwards;
  -moz-animation: done 1s 121.6s ease forwards;
  -webkit-animation: done 1s 121.6s ease forwards;
}

/* Initial counter state */
.number:after {
  display: block;
  width: 155px;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  animation: counter 120s 1s linear forwards;
  -o-animation: counter 120s 1s linear forwards;
  -moz-animation: counter 120s 1s linear forwards;
  -webkit-animation: counter 120s 1s linear forwards;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0 2px;
  content: "02:00";
}

/* ----- Keyframes ----- */
/* Countdown */
@-webkit-keyframes counter {
  /*119 seconds*/
  0.83333% {
    content: "01:59";
  }
  /*118 seconds*/
  1.66667% {
    content: "01:58";
  }
  /*117 seconds*/
  2.5% {
    content: "01:57";
  }
  /*116 seconds*/
  3.33333% {
    content: "01:56";
  }
  /*115 seconds*/
  4.16667% {
    content: "01:55";
  }
  /*114 seconds*/
  5% {
    content: "01:54";
  }
  /*113 seconds*/
  5.83333% {
    content: "01:53";
  }
  /*112 seconds*/
  6.66667% {
    content: "01:52";
  }
  /*111 seconds*/
  7.5% {
    content: "01:51";
  }
  /*110 seconds*/
  8.33333% {
    content: "01:50";
  }
  /*109 seconds*/
  9.16667% {
    content: "01:49";
  }
  /*108 seconds*/
  10% {
    content: "01:48";
  }
  /*107 seconds*/
  10.83333% {
    content: "01:47";
  }
  /*106 seconds*/
  11.66667% {
    content: "01:46";
  }
  /*105 seconds*/
  12.5% {
    content: "01:45";
  }
  /*104 seconds*/
  13.33333% {
    content: "01:44";
  }
  /*103 seconds*/
  14.16667% {
    content: "01:43";
  }
  /*102 seconds*/
  15% {
    content: "01:42";
  }
  /*101 seconds*/
  15.83333% {
    content: "01:41";
  }
  /*100 seconds*/
  16.66667% {
    content: "01:40";
  }
  /*99 seconds*/
  17.5% {
    content: "01:39";
  }
  /*98 seconds*/
  18.33333% {
    content: "01:38";
  }
  /*97 seconds*/
  19.16667% {
    content: "01:37";
  }
  /*96 seconds*/
  20% {
    content: "01:36";
  }
  /*95 seconds*/
  20.83333% {
    content: "01:35";
  }
  /*94 seconds*/
  21.66667% {
    content: "01:34";
  }
  /*93 seconds*/
  22.5% {
    content: "01:33";
  }
  /*92 seconds*/
  23.33333% {
    content: "01:32";
  }
  /*91 seconds*/
  24.16667% {
    content: "01:31";
  }
  /*90 seconds*/
  25% {
    content: "01:30";
  }
  /*89 seconds*/
  25.83333% {
    content: "01:29";
  }
  /*88 seconds*/
  26.66667% {
    content: "01:28";
  }
  /*87 seconds*/
  27.5% {
    content: "01:27";
  }
  /*86 seconds*/
  28.33333% {
    content: "01:26";
  }
  /*85 seconds*/
  29.16667% {
    content: "01:25";
  }
  /*84 seconds*/
  30% {
    content: "01:24";
  }
  /*83 seconds*/
  30.83333% {
    content: "01:23";
  }
  /*82 seconds*/
  31.66667% {
    content: "01:22";
  }
  /*81 seconds*/
  32.5% {
    content: "01:21";
  }
  /*80 seconds*/
  33.33333% {
    content: "01:20";
  }
  /*79 seconds*/
  34.16667% {
    content: "01:19";
  }
  /*78 seconds*/
  35% {
    content: "01:18";
  }
  /*77 seconds*/
  35.83333% {
    content: "01:17";
  }
  /*76 seconds*/
  36.66667% {
    content: "01:16";
  }
  /*75 seconds*/
  37.5% {
    content: "01:15";
  }
  /*74 seconds*/
  38.33333% {
    content: "01:14";
  }
  /*73 seconds*/
  39.16667% {
    content: "01:13";
  }
  /*72 seconds*/
  40% {
    content: "01:12";
  }
  /*71 seconds*/
  40.83333% {
    content: "01:11";
  }
  /*70 seconds*/
  41.66667% {
    content: "01:10";
  }
  /*69 seconds*/
  42.5% {
    content: "01:09";
  }
  /*68 seconds*/
  43.33333% {
    content: "01:08";
  }
  /*67 seconds*/
  44.16667% {
    content: "01:07";
  }
  /*66 seconds*/
  45% {
    content: "01:06";
  }
  /*65 seconds*/
  45.83333% {
    content: "01:05";
  }
  /*64 seconds*/
  46.66667% {
    content: "01:04";
  }
  /*63 seconds*/
  47.5% {
    content: "01:03";
  }
  /*62 seconds*/
  48.33333% {
    content: "01:02";
  }
  /*61 seconds*/
  49.16667% {
    content: "01:01";
  }
  /*60 seconds*/
  50% {
    content: "01:00";
  }
  /*59 seconds*/
  50.83333% {
    content: "00:59";
  }
  /*58 seconds*/
  51.66667% {
    content: "00:58";
  }
  /*57 seconds*/
  52.5% {
    content: "00:57";
  }
  /*56 seconds*/
  53.33333% {
    content: "00:56";
  }
  /*55 seconds*/
  54.16667% {
    content: "00:55";
  }
  /*54 seconds*/
  55% {
    content: "00:54";
  }
  /*53 seconds*/
  55.83333% {
    content: "00:53";
  }
  /*52 seconds*/
  56.66667% {
    content: "00:52";
  }
  /*51 seconds*/
  57.5% {
    content: "00:51";
  }
  /*50 seconds*/
  58.33333% {
    content: "00:50";
  }
  /*49 seconds*/
  59.16667% {
    content: "00:49";
  }
  /*48 seconds*/
  60% {
    content: "00:48";
  }
  /*47 seconds*/
  60.83333% {
    content: "00:47";
  }
  /*46 seconds*/
  61.66667% {
    content: "00:46";
  }
  /*45 seconds*/
  62.5% {
    content: "00:45";
  }
  /*44 seconds*/
  63.33333% {
    content: "00:44";
  }
  /*43 seconds*/
  64.16667% {
    content: "00:43";
  }
  /*42 seconds*/
  65% {
    content: "00:42";
  }
  /*41 seconds*/
  65.83333% {
    content: "00:41";
  }
  /*40 seconds*/
  66.66667% {
    content: "00:40";
  }
  /*39 seconds*/
  67.5% {
    content: "00:39";
  }
  /*38 seconds*/
  68.33333% {
    content: "00:38";
  }
  /*37 seconds*/
  69.16667% {
    content: "00:37";
  }
  /*36 seconds*/
  70% {
    content: "00:36";
  }
  /*35 seconds*/
  70.83333% {
    content: "00:35";
  }
  /*34 seconds*/
  71.66667% {
    content: "00:34";
  }
  /*33 seconds*/
  72.5% {
    content: "00:33";
  }
  /*32 seconds*/
  73.33333% {
    content: "00:32";
  }
  /*31 seconds*/
  74.16667% {
    content: "00:31";
  }
  /*30 seconds*/
  75% {
    content: "00:30";
  }
  /*29 seconds*/
  75.83333% {
    content: "00:29";
  }
  /*28 seconds*/
  76.66667% {
    content: "00:28";
  }
  /*27 seconds*/
  77.5% {
    content: "00:27";
  }
  /*26 seconds*/
  78.33333% {
    content: "00:26";
  }
  /*25 seconds*/
  79.16667% {
    content: "00:25";
  }
  /*24 seconds*/
  80% {
    content: "00:24";
  }
  /*23 seconds*/
  80.83333% {
    content: "00:23";
  }
  /*22 seconds*/
  81.66667% {
    content: "00:22";
  }
  /*21 seconds*/
  82.5% {
    content: "00:21";
  }
  /*20 seconds*/
  83.33333% {
    content: "00:20";
  }
  /*19 seconds*/
  84.16667% {
    content: "00:19";
  }
  /*18 seconds*/
  85% {
    content: "00:18";
  }
  /*17 seconds*/
  85.83333% {
    content: "00:17";
  }
  /*16 seconds*/
  86.66667% {
    content: "00:16";
  }
  /*15 seconds*/
  87.5% {
    content: "00:15";
  }
  /*14 seconds*/
  88.33333% {
    content: "00:14";
  }
  /*13 seconds*/
  89.16667% {
    content: "00:13";
  }
  /*12 seconds*/
  90% {
    content: "00:12";
  }
  /*11 seconds*/
  90.83333% {
    content: "00:11";
  }
  /*10 seconds*/
  91.66667% {
    content: "00:10";
  }
  /*9 seconds*/
  92.5% {
    content: "00:09";
  }
  /*8 seconds*/
  93.33333% {
    content: "00:08";
  }
  /*7 seconds*/
  94.16667% {
    content: "00:07";
  }
  /*6 seconds*/
  95% {
    content: "00:06";
  }
  /*5 seconds*/
  95.83333% {
    content: "00:05";
  }
  /*4 seconds*/
  96.66667% {
    content: "00:04";
  }
  /*3 seconds*/
  97.5% {
    content: "00:03";
  }
  /*2 seconds*/
  98.33333% {
    content: "00:02";
  }
  /*1 seconds*/
  99.16667% {
    content: "00:01";
  }
  /*0 seconds*/
  100% {
    content: "00:00";
  }
}
@keyframes counter {
  /*119 seconds*/
  0.83333% {
    content: "01:59";
  }
  /*118 seconds*/
  1.66667% {
    content: "01:58";
  }
  /*117 seconds*/
  2.5% {
    content: "01:57";
  }
  /*116 seconds*/
  3.33333% {
    content: "01:56";
  }
  /*115 seconds*/
  4.16667% {
    content: "01:55";
  }
  /*114 seconds*/
  5% {
    content: "01:54";
  }
  /*113 seconds*/
  5.83333% {
    content: "01:53";
  }
  /*112 seconds*/
  6.66667% {
    content: "01:52";
  }
  /*111 seconds*/
  7.5% {
    content: "01:51";
  }
  /*110 seconds*/
  8.33333% {
    content: "01:50";
  }
  /*109 seconds*/
  9.16667% {
    content: "01:49";
  }
  /*108 seconds*/
  10% {
    content: "01:48";
  }
  /*107 seconds*/
  10.83333% {
    content: "01:47";
  }
  /*106 seconds*/
  11.66667% {
    content: "01:46";
  }
  /*105 seconds*/
  12.5% {
    content: "01:45";
  }
  /*104 seconds*/
  13.33333% {
    content: "01:44";
  }
  /*103 seconds*/
  14.16667% {
    content: "01:43";
  }
  /*102 seconds*/
  15% {
    content: "01:42";
  }
  /*101 seconds*/
  15.83333% {
    content: "01:41";
  }
  /*100 seconds*/
  16.66667% {
    content: "01:40";
  }
  /*99 seconds*/
  17.5% {
    content: "01:39";
  }
  /*98 seconds*/
  18.33333% {
    content: "01:38";
  }
  /*97 seconds*/
  19.16667% {
    content: "01:37";
  }
  /*96 seconds*/
  20% {
    content: "01:36";
  }
  /*95 seconds*/
  20.83333% {
    content: "01:35";
  }
  /*94 seconds*/
  21.66667% {
    content: "01:34";
  }
  /*93 seconds*/
  22.5% {
    content: "01:33";
  }
  /*92 seconds*/
  23.33333% {
    content: "01:32";
  }
  /*91 seconds*/
  24.16667% {
    content: "01:31";
  }
  /*90 seconds*/
  25% {
    content: "01:30";
  }
  /*89 seconds*/
  25.83333% {
    content: "01:29";
  }
  /*88 seconds*/
  26.66667% {
    content: "01:28";
  }
  /*87 seconds*/
  27.5% {
    content: "01:27";
  }
  /*86 seconds*/
  28.33333% {
    content: "01:26";
  }
  /*85 seconds*/
  29.16667% {
    content: "01:25";
  }
  /*84 seconds*/
  30% {
    content: "01:24";
  }
  /*83 seconds*/
  30.83333% {
    content: "01:23";
  }
  /*82 seconds*/
  31.66667% {
    content: "01:22";
  }
  /*81 seconds*/
  32.5% {
    content: "01:21";
  }
  /*80 seconds*/
  33.33333% {
    content: "01:20";
  }
  /*79 seconds*/
  34.16667% {
    content: "01:19";
  }
  /*78 seconds*/
  35% {
    content: "01:18";
  }
  /*77 seconds*/
  35.83333% {
    content: "01:17";
  }
  /*76 seconds*/
  36.66667% {
    content: "01:16";
  }
  /*75 seconds*/
  37.5% {
    content: "01:15";
  }
  /*74 seconds*/
  38.33333% {
    content: "01:14";
  }
  /*73 seconds*/
  39.16667% {
    content: "01:13";
  }
  /*72 seconds*/
  40% {
    content: "01:12";
  }
  /*71 seconds*/
  40.83333% {
    content: "01:11";
  }
  /*70 seconds*/
  41.66667% {
    content: "01:10";
  }
  /*69 seconds*/
  42.5% {
    content: "01:09";
  }
  /*68 seconds*/
  43.33333% {
    content: "01:08";
  }
  /*67 seconds*/
  44.16667% {
    content: "01:07";
  }
  /*66 seconds*/
  45% {
    content: "01:06";
  }
  /*65 seconds*/
  45.83333% {
    content: "01:05";
  }
  /*64 seconds*/
  46.66667% {
    content: "01:04";
  }
  /*63 seconds*/
  47.5% {
    content: "01:03";
  }
  /*62 seconds*/
  48.33333% {
    content: "01:02";
  }
  /*61 seconds*/
  49.16667% {
    content: "01:01";
  }
  /*60 seconds*/
  50% {
    content: "01:00";
  }
  /*59 seconds*/
  50.83333% {
    content: "00:59";
  }
  /*58 seconds*/
  51.66667% {
    content: "00:58";
  }
  /*57 seconds*/
  52.5% {
    content: "00:57";
  }
  /*56 seconds*/
  53.33333% {
    content: "00:56";
  }
  /*55 seconds*/
  54.16667% {
    content: "00:55";
  }
  /*54 seconds*/
  55% {
    content: "00:54";
  }
  /*53 seconds*/
  55.83333% {
    content: "00:53";
  }
  /*52 seconds*/
  56.66667% {
    content: "00:52";
  }
  /*51 seconds*/
  57.5% {
    content: "00:51";
  }
  /*50 seconds*/
  58.33333% {
    content: "00:50";
  }
  /*49 seconds*/
  59.16667% {
    content: "00:49";
  }
  /*48 seconds*/
  60% {
    content: "00:48";
  }
  /*47 seconds*/
  60.83333% {
    content: "00:47";
  }
  /*46 seconds*/
  61.66667% {
    content: "00:46";
  }
  /*45 seconds*/
  62.5% {
    content: "00:45";
  }
  /*44 seconds*/
  63.33333% {
    content: "00:44";
  }
  /*43 seconds*/
  64.16667% {
    content: "00:43";
  }
  /*42 seconds*/
  65% {
    content: "00:42";
  }
  /*41 seconds*/
  65.83333% {
    content: "00:41";
  }
  /*40 seconds*/
  66.66667% {
    content: "00:40";
  }
  /*39 seconds*/
  67.5% {
    content: "00:39";
  }
  /*38 seconds*/
  68.33333% {
    content: "00:38";
  }
  /*37 seconds*/
  69.16667% {
    content: "00:37";
  }
  /*36 seconds*/
  70% {
    content: "00:36";
  }
  /*35 seconds*/
  70.83333% {
    content: "00:35";
  }
  /*34 seconds*/
  71.66667% {
    content: "00:34";
  }
  /*33 seconds*/
  72.5% {
    content: "00:33";
  }
  /*32 seconds*/
  73.33333% {
    content: "00:32";
  }
  /*31 seconds*/
  74.16667% {
    content: "00:31";
  }
  /*30 seconds*/
  75% {
    content: "00:30";
  }
  /*29 seconds*/
  75.83333% {
    content: "00:29";
  }
  /*28 seconds*/
  76.66667% {
    content: "00:28";
  }
  /*27 seconds*/
  77.5% {
    content: "00:27";
  }
  /*26 seconds*/
  78.33333% {
    content: "00:26";
  }
  /*25 seconds*/
  79.16667% {
    content: "00:25";
  }
  /*24 seconds*/
  80% {
    content: "00:24";
  }
  /*23 seconds*/
  80.83333% {
    content: "00:23";
  }
  /*22 seconds*/
  81.66667% {
    content: "00:22";
  }
  /*21 seconds*/
  82.5% {
    content: "00:21";
  }
  /*20 seconds*/
  83.33333% {
    content: "00:20";
  }
  /*19 seconds*/
  84.16667% {
    content: "00:19";
  }
  /*18 seconds*/
  85% {
    content: "00:18";
  }
  /*17 seconds*/
  85.83333% {
    content: "00:17";
  }
  /*16 seconds*/
  86.66667% {
    content: "00:16";
  }
  /*15 seconds*/
  87.5% {
    content: "00:15";
  }
  /*14 seconds*/
  88.33333% {
    content: "00:14";
  }
  /*13 seconds*/
  89.16667% {
    content: "00:13";
  }
  /*12 seconds*/
  90% {
    content: "00:12";
  }
  /*11 seconds*/
  90.83333% {
    content: "00:11";
  }
  /*10 seconds*/
  91.66667% {
    content: "00:10";
  }
  /*9 seconds*/
  92.5% {
    content: "00:09";
  }
  /*8 seconds*/
  93.33333% {
    content: "00:08";
  }
  /*7 seconds*/
  94.16667% {
    content: "00:07";
  }
  /*6 seconds*/
  95% {
    content: "00:06";
  }
  /*5 seconds*/
  95.83333% {
    content: "00:05";
  }
  /*4 seconds*/
  96.66667% {
    content: "00:04";
  }
  /*3 seconds*/
  97.5% {
    content: "00:03";
  }
  /*2 seconds*/
  98.33333% {
    content: "00:02";
  }
  /*1 seconds*/
  99.16667% {
    content: "00:01";
  }
  /*0 seconds*/
  100% {
    content: "00:00";
  }
}
/* Move out counter */
@-webkit-keyframes number {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -25%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -25%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -210%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -210%);
  }
}
@keyframes number {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
  20% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -25%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -25%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -210%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -210%);
  }
}
/* Circle progress */
@-webkit-keyframes circle {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 650;
  }
}
@keyframes circle {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 650;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <svg>
        <!--Used for the drop shadow -->
        <path class="circle shadow" d="M200.2,302c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2,0c-56.9,0-103-46.1-103-103S143.1,96,200,96s103,46.1,103,103
   c0,56.8-45.9,102.8-102.6,103C200.3,302,200.3,302,200.2,302"/>
        <!-- Colored circle -->
        <path class="circle" d="M200.2,302c-0.1,0-0.2,0-0.2,0c-56.9,0-103-46.1-103-103S143.1,96,200,96s103,46.1,103,103
      c0,56.8-45.9,102.8-102.6,103C200.3,302,200.3,302,200.2,302"/>
    </svg>

    <div class="mask">
        <div class="number"></div>
        <p>DONE</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I've got no good news for you if you want a CSS-only solution.

No, the content property is not "keyframable", because the content property takes in a string. Keyframes can only animate things that are numbers. You can't keyframe "visibility" or "box-sizing" because the values for those properties aren't numbers. Similarly, you can keyframe something like "margin" so long as the result is a number, and not "auto".

Even if you use a number in the content property, it's still considered a string, so it can't be keyframed.

Unfortunately, no, IE does not allow you to animate the stroke properties in an SVG.

Answer (score 0):

After further researches, I ended up on css-tricks.
https://css-tricks.com/animating-the-content-property/

Basically, the content property isn't listed as animatable by the W3C. Even though that is true for almost all browsers, the newest versions of chrome now support it.

Conclusion of the experiment:
Always use javascript to animate the `content` Property!